# Does Orion support GeoJSON format?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying to create an entity using GeoJSON for it location:

```
{
 "id": "1234",
 "name": "test",
 "type": "TestDevice",

   "location": {
    "value": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [2.186447514, 41.3763726, 143.148]
    },
    "type": "geo:json"
  }
}
```

but I am getting this error:

```
{
    "error": "BadRequest",
    "description": "attribute must be a JSON object, unless keyValues option is used"
}
```

Does the GeoJSON supported by Orion?

I am using orion on docker:

```
 "version": "1.8.0-next"
```

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem of geo:json support
It is the attribute name that causes this issue. It should be like the following:

```
{
 "id": "1234",
 "name": {
    "value": "test",
    "type": "String"
  },
 "type": "TestDevice",

   "location": {
    "value": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [2.186447514, 41.3763726, 143.148]
    },
    "type": "geo:json"
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could include in your self-answer which was the exact cause of the problem and how did you solved ;)